# Radio button checked not working in the partial view but working in the main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

Radio button checked not working in the partial view. But working in the main view page. also if I use checkbox instead of radio it works fine in the partial view.

```
Code:-


   <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="phonetic" name="languageSelector">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>Phonetic
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="bijoy" name="languageSelector">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> Bijoy
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="avro" checked="checked" name="languageSelector">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>Avro
   </label>
```

Comment: What you mean working/not working ? Can you explain what your expected behavior is ? It is hard to comprehend from the code you shared.

Comment: Radio button CHECKED option showing checked in the main view. But same thing not showing in the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having an issue with the way you're referencing your partial view. There are two ways of doing so:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialExample") and @Html.RenderPartial("_PartialExample")
```

One is written into the HTTP response, the other is rendered as an HTML encoded string. Try both and see if that helps.

Here's more information about what I'm talking about.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/partial-view-in-mvc/